# I want to vectorize when I use for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a question about vectorizing. But I have to say sorry, because I am newbie about R.

When I use for loop like this,

```
For (i in 1:10){
2^i
}
```

And I tried it for vectorize like this.

```
a <- For (i in 1:10){
2^i
}
```

But there’s not I wanted.
My wanted result is `a = 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024`
But result is `a = NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1024`.

I don’t know what’s the problem.
I think, there are some method for vectorize ‘for loop’ but just I don’t know it. But I cannot unable to grab a border...

Comment: `2^(1:10)` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case `2^(1:10)` would work, you will learn that there are many things that can be done by loops, but have much easier solutions.

But for you to understand how to do it with a loop, you first need to create an empty variable and them assign the values of your loop to it:

```
a = numeric()
for (i in 1:10){
a[i] = 2^i
}
```